# CUDA copy and kernel call within a loop

Tags: c, cuda

So I am working on an assignment which involves coding in C using CUDA. I have written a function and a kernel that work (produce the correct result). However, I am looking to increase the speed.

This is the kernel:

```
__global__ void update_c(const double *d_u, double *d_u_new, const int nx, const double k)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < nx-1 && i > 0)
    {
        d_u_new[i] =  d_u[i] + k*(d_u[i+1] + d_u[i-1] -2*d_u[i]);
    }
}
```

and this is the function:

```
void update() {

  cudaMemcpy(d_u, u, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_u_new, u_new, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  update_c<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_u, d_u_new, nx, k);
  cudaMemcpy(u, d_u, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(u_new, d_u_new, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  double *tmp = u_new; u_new = u; u = tmp;
}
```

I understand that once copied d_u and d_u_new will stay on the device so I do not need to copy them each time. My question is how do I re-write this to use the variables over and over and only copy memory at the start and end of the program? I am brand new to CUDA and only got a very brief crash course in it before this was assigned.

Comment: We need to see the code that calls `update()` to really know. Could you add more context?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by creating the following:

```
__global__ void update_c(const double *d_u, double *d_u_new, const int nx, const double k)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < nx-1 && i > 0)
    {
        d_u_new[i] =  d_u[i] + k*(d_u[i+1] + d_u[i-1] -2*d_u[i]);
    }
}

void copyToDev(){
  cudaMemcpy(d_u, u, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_u_new, u_new, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}

void copyToHost(){
  cudaMemcpy(u, d_u, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(u_new, d_u_new, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

/* updates u for next time step. */
void update() {

  update_c<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_u, d_u_new, nx, k);
  double *tmp = d_u_new; d_u_new = d_u; d_u = tmp;
}
```

I call copyToDev() before the loop that calls update and copyToHost after.